# Assistance with Gradle in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to get gradle project support in my latest eclipse. I installed the [official gradle plugin](http://gradle.org/press-release/eclipse-gradle/) from eclipse marketplace. I downloaded a couple of gradle based projects randomly from github (just to test) and whenever I import any of them, they start downloading a different gradle zip for each project. `gradle-2.2.1-all.zip` and `gradle-2.9-all.zip` and others.

and I end up getting this error when it's downloaded, it never lets me import the project:

> Synchronize Gradle builds with workspace failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
>   Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-all.zip'.
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':cSploit'.
>   SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
>   org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-all.zip'.

so the questions are:

1) do I need a different gradle zip for each project?

2) do I need to download the same zip again if I import the same project again after switching to some other project?

3) can't I just download the latest gradle zip which is supported by all projects?

4) how do I fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle, Android and the ANDROID\_HOME SDK location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794200/gradle-android-and-the-android-home-sdk-location)

Answer (score 0):

> Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

All versions of Gradle are going to give you that error. The reason those github projects do not contain that file is because it is specific to **your** computer, therefore isn't committed to source control.

To do so, create `local.properties` in the root of your project and add this (of course updating the path)

```
sdk.dir=/path/to/android/sdk
```

If you would like to use consistent versions of Gradle, edit the `distributionUrl` value in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: You should preferably using the latest Gradle distribution. You don't need to download individual/older versions for various projects, it should be downloaded to your user's home folder

Comment: Refer to the duplicate question I flagged above

Comment: Depends on your computer, but I think on Linux or Mac, there is a `.gradle` or `.m2` hidden folder in your User home directory where it is downloaded

Comment: Of download it manually. Eclipse does not include it.  http://gradle.org/gradle-download/

Comment: Look at the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file. I think it's all. As I said, though, Gradle will download the wrapper on its own. You shouldn't need to do it yourself. Plus you'll need to additionally change some settings to point Gradle at the file you download

Comment: There should be a wrapper folder. At least that is the standard Android Studio project layout. Alternatively, Android Studio is a great IDE

Comment: That's the wrong file. Please carefully compare the names I have mentioned

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, then. The folder that you use should be the folder that contains `build-tools` and `platform-tools`

Comment: I've had problems with the ANDROID_HOME variable not getting read. I think you need `D:\\sdk` because that backslash needs escaped

Comment: tried `D:\\sdk` already, but some other path is still overriding my path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114301/discussion-between-cricket-007-and-abbie).

Comment: You can read about [Environment Variables](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) if you want