# Add Spotify Web API to android

Tags: android, spotify

I'm having trouble understanding how to add this api:

https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android

I'm on Windows 10 so I download and navigate to the folder in cmd and type "./gradlew assemble" but I get errors

> A problem occurred configuring project ':sample-search'.
>
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

I'm not sure if there is more to the process. From my understanding this creates a aar file that I can then add to my main project.

Or if there are other simpler suggestions to adding web api functions let me know.

Comment: "Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties".. Did you search for that message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle, Android and the ANDROID\_HOME SDK location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794200/gradle-android-and-the-android-home-sdk-location)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176594/android-sdk-location  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042638/how-do-i-set-android-sdk-home-environment-variable   Set ANDROID_HOME environment variable your sdk might not be correctly set up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24804399/4608334 check this out

Comment: I pretty much copied my local.properties file from my project. put that in the folder i downloaded and now its an error "failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in 'C:\path-to-sdk'

Comment: pfft simple enough, I just needed android build tools 23.* from the sdk manager. Thanks. Time to code!

Answer (score 0):

locate `local.properties` on root folder of your project, input location of android sdk, example:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\android\\tool\\adk\\sdk
```